# Scheme - how to find index of character while going through string

Tags: hash, scheme, lambda

Having a problem with a function I'm writing in Scheme. The method takes a word represented as list of symbols as input, and for each character, does a hashing equation and returns a value. The final value is the sum of the hash value for each character in the set.

Imagine a string as an array of characters, 'w', where w[i] is the index of each character in the array.

The equation is the sum of --> 7^i * ctv(w[i]) for each character in the word.

For each letter where ctv (“character-to-value”) maps ‘a’ to 1, ‘b’ to 2, ... and ‘z’ to 26.

For example, key(“d a y”)
     = (7^0 * ctv (’d’)) + (7^1 ctv(‘a’)) + (7^2 ctv(‘y’)) = 1236

SO, my actual question about this is how I find the index, the i in w[i] for each character in the word.
Here is my first thought, using (length w) as the index but I know this is incorrect.

```
(define keys
  (lambda(w)
    (if(null? w)
      0
    (+ (* (ctv(car w)) (expt 7 (length w)))  (keys (cdr w)))))
   )
```

My next thought was maybe it a lambda for size, like this. 
*Note* - I know it would need to be changed to (size-1).

```
(define keys
  (lambda(size)
    (lambda(w)
      (if(null? w)
        0
      (+ (* (ctv(car w)) (expt 7 (size w)))  (keys (cdr w)))))
     )
```

But even then, the size would still the be opposite end of the index, for example with 'day', size-1 for 'd' would be 2, and size-1 for 'y' would be 0.

Anyway, if anyone has any idea what I'm talking about and has a possible solution or advice, please reply!!

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to pass along the index as a parameter, and increment it at the same time that you traverse the list. Also, it's easier if we transform the input string into a list of chars, For example:

```
(define (key word)
  (let loop ((chars (string->list word)) ; list of chars
             (idx 0)  ; current index
             (acc 0)) ; accumulated result
    (if (null? chars) ; if the list is empty
        acc           ; return the accumulator
        (loop (cdr chars) ; otherwise go to the next char
              (add1 idx)  ; advance the index
              (+ acc (* (expt 7 idx) (ctv (car chars)))))))) ; compute result
```

Assuming that the `ctv` procedure is correctly implemented, it should work as expected:

```
(key "day")
=> 1236
```

Comment: Getting the following error: 

string->list: expects argument of type <string>; given (h e l l o). The words to test the program are previously defined such as this: (define hello '(h e l l o)), so I can run 'keys' on hello. So all words need to be represented as a set of symbols.

Comment: Also getting this error for the multiplication part in the last line:  

*: expects type <number> as 2nd argument, given: #<void>; other arguments were: 1

Comment: @RCouch for the first error: in your question you say that the input looks like `"day"`, please update the question with the _real values_ that are supposed to be used as input. For the second error: that's because there's a mistake in your implementation of `ctv`, currently it's returning `#<void>`, you must fix it and test it properly for this algorithm to work.

Comment: @RCouch By the way: using a list of symbols for this problem is a _real hassle_, you want _chars_, not _symbols_ for your algorithm, It'll be much simpler if you just use a string as input, like you did in the current question

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is also tagged *Racket*, you might appreciate an elegant, Racket-only solution using [for/sum](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Fsum#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fsum%29%29) and [in-indexed](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-indexed#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-indexed%29%29):

```
(define (key word)
  (for/sum (((c i) (in-indexed word)))
    (* (expt 7 i) (cvt c))))
```

Testing:

```
> (key "day")
1236
```

Comment: Removed the racket tag... It's actually required for it to be in scheme and not racket.